# How to get file and upload to server using php jquery without form tag

Tags: php, jquery

How to get file and upload to server  folder and filename to database using php jquery without form tag using there id here's the code

```
<input type="file" name="upload" id="upload">
```

Comment: Please read **Related**

Comment: i don't have a form tag i want to get file through there id

Comment: You don't need a form tag if you are doing it asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery plugin for this.Check documentation here.As per my knowledge you want to submit the file without page refresh.

http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic.html